# Disadvantage of using Polymorphism (Technical)

Tags: c++, polymorphism

**I know the main advantages of polymorphism which are**

1. It helps the programmers to reuse the code and classes once written,
   tested and implemented. They can be reused in many cases.
2. Single variable can be used to store multiple data types.
3. It reduces coupling.

But when I searched for its disadvantages I got answers like

1. It's esoteric. Not very easy for the beginner to just pick up and go
   with it. Rather it takes often years of dedication before
   abstraction becomes second nature.

**What I want to know is whether there are any technical disadvantages to using polymorphism?**

Comment: I have exactly the opposite experience, beginners often abuse polymorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Below are few technical Disadvantages.**

- Run time polymorphism makes performance issue as it needs to decide
  at run time so it degrade the performance if there are lot of virtual
  functions.
- 4 bytes (it can be different practically) of vptr (virtual pointer) and overhead of look-up table.

Comment: You can do polymorphism in different ways. You don’t necessarily need virtual functions for it.

Comment: But for runtime polymorphism You surely needs Virtual Functions in c++ .Without that You can not achieve Runtime Polymorphism.

Comment: pointers are not always 4 bytes

Comment: You can achieve runtime polymorphism with a custom table (not that it would have any advantages), or with a switch statement, for example.

Comment: @rightfold switch statement is not polymorphic, because it works only on pre-written cases.

Comment: @SargeBorsch yes pointer can be of 4 or 8 byte .

Comment: @farhangdon Theoretically, it can have any size which is practical... so you'd better not write any numbers.

Comment: @SargeBorsch okay. I will update it.Thanks

Comment: @rightfold can You please explain your opinion ? I want to know that further.

Comment: Sadly the OP has been hit with overzealous zapping. I add that while a call to virtualFunction () will have additional overhead, the alternative is to select the correct function using a switch or if statement that also adds overhead. So the the performance is not bad in most cases.

Comment: It doesn't 'degrade the performance if there are a lot of virtual functions'. A virtual function embodies a choice that would have to be made in some other way if the function wasn't virtual. It isn't valid to compare the performance of a virtual vs non-virtual function call without taking that into account. Without non-virtual there would have to be an `if` or `switch` or pointer deference or something.

Answer (score 1):

Virtual method calls (dynamic dispatch) have a slight run-time penalty, as it needs to resolve the function to be called at the time of the call. In general, this performance penalty is nothing to be worried about. However, I did some testing a couple of years back; you may experience noticeable slowdowns if you're making a lot of virtual calls and these resolve to a different function each time. This is because it messes with the CPU's branch prediction.